# grunt-init copyAndProcess corrupting png files

Tags: gruntjs

I've just started using grunt-init.  I have everything working, except I'm finding that any images/*.png files in my template get corrupted in transit to the destination folder.

I suspect that the init.copyAndProcess function is corrupting them (they open in Gimp from the template folder but not the destination folder).

How can I do a copy instead of copyAndProcess for a subset of the files in my template?  Preferably using a pattern like 'images/**' to identify the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would have preferred something more concise, similar to what was already in the template.js:

```
var files = init.filesToCopy( props );
init.copyAndProcess( files, props );
```

But this works:

```
var src_path = init.srcpath( 'images/' );
var dest_path = init.destpath( ) + '/images/';

// Copy the images folder this way to prevent corrupting the files
grunt.file.recurse( src_path, function( abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename ) {
    if ( subdir == undefined ) {
        var dest = dest_path + filename;
    } else {
        var dest = dest_path + subdir + '/' + filename;
    }
    grunt.file.copy( abspath, dest );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can use filesToCopy, since you pass a noprocess hash, telling to grunt-init the files it should not process.

Refer to http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding#copying-files (grunt-init documentation) 
and an example at line 73 of this commit https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-jquery/blob/ecf070d7469d610441458111bc05cd543ee5bbc0/template.js.

Comment: Here's what's on line 73:
init.copyAndProcess(files, props, {noProcess: 'libs/**'});